# Properly splitting a string in UNIX shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to be able to split a string so that each string are passed as variable in my shell.

I tried something like this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

COMPOPT="CC=clang CXX=clang++"
$COMPOPT cmake ../gdcm
```

I also tried a bash specific solution, but with no luck so far:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash -x

COMPOPT="CC=clang CXX=clang++"
ARRAY=($COMPOPT)
"${ARRAY[0]}" "${ARRAY[1]}" cmake ../gdcm
```

I always get the non-informative error message:

```
./test.sh: 5: ./t.sh: CC=clang: not found
```

Of course if I try directly from the running shell this works:

```
$ CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake ../gdcm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `eval`-free solution is to use the `env` program:

```
env "${ARRAY[@]}" cmake ../gdm
```

which provides a level of indirection to the usual `FOO=BAR command` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
$COMPOPT cmake ../gdcm
```

the shell would attempt to execute the value of the variable as a *command*.

The [*evil* `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) is rather handy in such cases.  Say:

```
eval $COMPOPT cmake ../gdcm
```

Answer (score 1):

Though devnull's answer works but uses `eval` and that has known pitfalls.

Here is a way it can be done without invoking `eval`:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMPOPT="CC=clang CXX=clang++"
sh -c "$COMPOPT cmake ../gdcm"
```

i.e. pass the whole command line to `sh` (or bash).

Comment: How is that safer than using `eval`? If `$COMPOPT` is set to `rm -rf /; `, it will still get executed, no?

Comment: No I never claimed on safety, writing shell script has its own risk if one is not careful.